# Nami wallet showing getBalance returning a NaN

Tags: wallet, ada, address, api

Hi i just recently started working with Nami Wallet to be implementes in a web app, but when im trying to get my wallet balance:

```
window.cardano.getBalance().then(res => console.log(res))
```

its returning an string.

> "1a3b983883"

would love to know what that is and if i can convert that to an actual number.

Picture:

[image: getBalance() response]

Answer (score 7):

`getBalance` function returns cbor encoded hex string, so you should actually decode it.

Easiest way to do it is by using [Cardano Serialization Lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser).

After you've downloaded the library you can decoded it by doing this:

```
import * as wasm from '@emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib-browser';

window.cardano.getBalance().then(res => {
   const balance = wasm.Value.from_bytes(Buffer.from(res, 'hex'));
   const lovelaces = balance.coin().to_str();

   console.log(lovelaces);
})
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to [Hernan Rajchert](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/users/4593/hernan-rajchert) for explaining on how to get lovelaces from Values object.

Comment: thanks! but this code returns this object "{ptr: 1180552}", what to do with that?

Comment: Yeah I got the same response so I'm not too sure about it. I'd recommend you rather building your transactions using TransactionBuilder, because it offers you nice way to specify change address and etc.

Comment: @DanielDiaz, that is a pointer to the WASM object, if you need to get the lovelace value as string you can do `balance.coin().to_str()`

Comment: Yes as DanielDias suggested thats the way to go I got my balance in lovelaces

Comment: I'll update my answer and tag @HernanRajchert

Comment: Why do I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined"?

Comment: //another way to convert hex string to bytes without Buffer
function hexToBytes(hex) {
  for (var bytes = [], c = 0; c < hex.length; c += 2)
      bytes.push(parseInt(hex.substr(c, 2), 16));
  return bytes;
}

Comment: @HernanRajchert or anybody else know how I can view the contents of these WASM objects that you're referring to?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the `cbor` npm package to extract the balance value:

```
import cbor from 'cbor';

const getAdaBalance = (string) => {
  const decoded = cbor.decode(string)
  return ((typeof decoded === 'number') ? decoded : decoded[0]) / 1_000_000;
}

let myBalance = getAdaBalance(await window.cardano.getBalance());
```