# Nami getBalance() returns wrong value compared to GUI Wallet

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet

When I call cardano.getBalance() it does not show the same value as the Nami Wallet GUI shows.
The Nami Wallet shows ADA 99.73 and the getBalance() returns ADA 101.114713.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this chould help you out: https://cardano.stackexchange.com/a/4113/1045

Answer (score 3):

In Nami Wallet GUI you can see the amount of ADA excluding the ADA locked with assets (in your case it is 1.37928 ADA). You can see the "Locked with assets" amount in the hint ⓘ to the right of your Nami Wallet ADA amount.
[image]